# CSS Overflow, i want it

Tags: html, css, list, tree, overflow

I have a simple sheet styles, developed to show a tree. Each sheet can have many or any child.

With few nodes stylesheet performs well, but with large amounts behavior is not correct.

An example of the tree with fewer nodes (working properly):
[image: Example 1]

An example of the tree with many nodes (malfunctioning, you can see how the tree is cut and jumps down):
[image: Example 2]

If I force the div width to a specific width, I get the result I want, but I need the mechanism be automatic, and if possible keep pure CSS. Example tree working well, with the width set manually:
[image]

Being more specific, I seek the width of the tree be automatic regardless of the size of the screen, and make it necessary to use the scroll to see it completely. The content of the  tags can vary in length, so its size is self-adjusting.

Here is my stylesheet, and a sample tree:

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

/*.tree{width:3000px; margin:40px auto 0 auto}*/

.tree ul {
 padding-top: 20px; position: relative;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
 float: left; text-align: center;
 list-style-type: none;
 position: relative;
 padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
 content: '';
 position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
 border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
 right: auto; left: 50%;
 border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
 display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
 border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
 border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
 border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
 content: '';
 position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
 border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #666;
 font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
 font-size: 11px;
 display: inline-block;
 
 border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
 background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
 border-color:  #94a0b4;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name = "viewport" content="width = device-width">
    <title>tree</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="tree">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">0</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">1</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">4</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">9</a>
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">19</a>
                          <ul>
                            <li>
                              <a href="#">38</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                              <a href="#">39</a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">20</a>
                          <ul>
                            <li>
                              <a href="#">40</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                              <a href="#">41</a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">21</a>
                          <ul>
                            <li>
                              <a href="#">42</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                              <a href="#">43</a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">10</a>
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">22</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">23</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">11</a>
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">24</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">5</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">12</a>
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">25</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">26</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">27</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">13</a>
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">28</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">29</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">6</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">14</a>
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">30</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">31</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">2</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">7</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">15</a>
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">32</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">33</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">34</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">16</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">3</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">8</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">17</a>
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">35</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">36</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">37</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">18</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I appreciate the time you spend to help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Vertical or horizontal scroll?

Comment: @hello horizontal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 99% solution:

Give the DIV an actual width - 100% of its parent.

```
div.tree {
  margin:40px auto 0 auto;
  width:100%;
  overflow-x:auto; 
}
```

It seems to be the UL which is wrapping its contents.
Use nowrap to stop white space wrapping.

```
.tree ul {
  white-space:nowrap;
  padding-top: 20px; position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
 }
```

And lastly convert LI's into a block display, stop them floating left and, to repair the missing left float, align them with the top of their container.

```
.tree li {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

That missing 1% is the few pixels gap between horizontal lines. Not sure how to close this up. Margin and Padding perhaps? I can't seem to manage it.

Tested on FireFox Win7 64

Comment: Hi. I played a long time with the stylesheet to solve the 1%, but could not get it. Anyway, the solution is useful to me.

I had some problems (at least using Chrome), but I could solve them. With a large tree, the horizontal scroll overflowed down, and did not look. If performing zoom out, the bar looked coupled to the content, and not coupled to the browser.

Simply removing the div.tree properties, now it looks like I need.

I really appreciate your help. Now I'm using your solution. If in the future you resolve the problem of 1%, it will be well received.

Comment: Oh, it turned out to be a simple fix for that little gap, remove all the spaces between <LI> elements:



`<li><a href="#">32</a></li><li><a href="#">33</a></li><li><a href="#">34</a></li>`

Comment: I can not believe that was the reason for the problem! I have an algorithm that automatically generates the trees, and the HTML code generated is indented for readability. I solved the problem partially using negative margins in the <li>. Thank you, case closed!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
/*.tree{width:3000px; margin:40px auto 0 auto}*/
```

to

```
.tree{
    width: 2000px; 
    margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Adjust `width` as nodes in your tree grows.

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.tree{width: 2000px; margin:40px auto 0 auto;overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;}

.tree ul {
 padding-top: 20px; position: relative;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
 float: left; text-align: center;
 list-style-type: none;
 position: relative;
 padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
 content: '';
 position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
 border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
 right: auto; left: 50%;
 border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
 display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
 border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
 border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
 border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
 content: '';
 position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
 border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #666;
 font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
 font-size: 11px;
 display: inline-block;
 
 border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
 background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
 border-color:  #94a0b4;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div >

    <div class="tree">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">0</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">1</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">4</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">9</a>
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">19</a>
                          <ul>
                            <li>
                              <a href="#">38</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                              <a href="#">39</a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">20</a>
                          <ul>
                            <li>
                              <a href="#">40</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                              <a href="#">41</a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">21</a>
                          <ul>
                            <li>
                              <a href="#">42</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                              <a href="#">43</a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">10</a>
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">22</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">23</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">11</a>
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">24</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">5</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">12</a>
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">25</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">26</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">27</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">13</a>
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">28</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">29</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">6</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">14</a>
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">30</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">31</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">2</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">7</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">15</a>
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">32</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">33</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">34</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">16</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">3</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">8</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">17</a>
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">35</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">36</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">37</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">18</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: The second line of my code CSS, is what I mentioned I use to force the width, and I need the width be automatic. Once the width is automatic, I assume that the horizontal scroll bar appear alone. The solution you propose me not far from the current solution. I take this opportunity to thank you for your help.